# Passing custom class object when deploying verticles

Tags: java, vert.x, vertxoptions

I have a custom client object that I am instantiating in the main() method and need to pass it to all the verticle instances that I am going to deploy.
Here is what I have tried -

1.)

```
private static Connection connection;
.
.
.
//method to initialise client
initialiseClient();
final DeploymentOptions deployOpts = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(num_instances);
vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle(connection), deployOpts, ar -> {
                  if (ar.succeeded()) {
                      startFuture.complete();
                  } else {
                      startFuture.fail(ar.cause());
                  }
              });
```

In this case I am getting the following error because the verticle instance has already been created.

```
Can't specify > 1 instances for already created verticle
```

2.)

```
JsonObject object = new JsonObject().put("connection-object", connection); 
final DeploymentOptions deployOpts = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(num_instances);
vertx.deployVerticle(MyVerticle.class.getName(), deployOpts, ar -> {
                  if (ar.succeeded()) {
                      startFuture.complete();
                  } else {
                      startFuture.fail(ar.cause());
                  }
              });
```

In this case I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal type in JsonObject: class com.abc.def.Connection
```

So my question is, is there any way to pass a custom class object while deploying multiple instances of a verticle?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `deployVerticle` method that takes a `Supplier<Verticle>` (javadocs [here](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#deployVerticle-java.util.function.Supplier-io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions-)).

```java
DeploymentOptions deployOpts = new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(num_instances);
vertx.deployVerticle(() -> { return new MyVerticle(connection) }, deployOpts);
```